# prove that AD, BE, CF are also concurrent

Tags: geometry

equilateral triangles DBC, ECA and FAB are constructed externally on the sides BC,CA,AB respectively of triangle ABC. Prove that AD, BE, and CF are also concurrent.

i need an approach pl.
the 3 triangles are obviously similar..

Comment: You should add a figure.

Comment: This is part (3) of the question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109683/triangle-abc-and-equilateral-triangles-abc-bca-and-acb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection point is known as the [Fermat First Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point). It's the point from which the sum of the distance to each vertex is minimized. The proof that the three line concur at one point can be see in the link above.